# Catching exceptions in a multiprocessing loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, concurrency, python-multiprocessing

Is it possible to catch an exception raised from the loop in a callable from `concurrent.futures.Executor` such as this? --

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_cores) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(self._process_ticket, i) for i in items}
    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

I am trying to loop through thousands of objects in a list to perform tasks on and just set up multiprocessing to process them quicker. This is working great but because of the objects I am working on there is a possibility an exception can be raised from the `for` loop during the process and because it is being called by `concurrent.futures.Executor` I am unable to catch it the way I was catching it previously.

Below is a simple example of how I was catching exceptions previously through a serialized process. I had to create a workaround to force the iteration to try and process the object again and continue from that step forward as the exception causes the loop to stop:

```py
def task(self, items, step=None):
    # items = [list,of,many,objects]
    try:
        for i in range(0 if step is None else step, len(items)):
            with app.app_context():
                ## do things with items[i]..
    except Exception as e:
        self.task(items, i)
```

I'm basically wanting to force an object to be processed again in the event the loop is interrupted by an exception and continue the loop from that step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, figured this out a few days ago. Not sure if this is the best/recommended way to get this done but it seems to get the job done:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_cores) as executor:
    try:
        for i in range(step, len(items)):
            futures = {executor.submit(self.task, items[i])}
    except:
        self.task(items, i)

    concurrent.futures.wait(futures)
```

Still open for suggestions/advice